# How can I renumber IDs in my simple-orm database after deleting a record?

Tags: python, discord.py

This is my code:

```
@Bot.command()
async def kod_sil(ctx):
    objects = Code.manager(db)
    code_list = list(objects.all())
    i = 1
    while i <= len(code_list):
        usercode = objects.get(i)
        usercode2 = usercode.__dict__
        kullanici = usercode2.get('discord_id')
        mesajsahibi = ctx.message.author.id
        if kullanici == mesajsahibi:
            usercode.delete()
        
        i = i + 1
   
    db.commit()
```

I want to use

```
usercode.delete()
```

But when command delete usercode from table it delete with id.Example: i delete usercode id.1 after that, table starts with 2. id. How i can fix it?When IDs starting with 2. at this command:

```
i = 1
while i <= len(code_list):
    usercode = objects.get(i)
```

objects.get command cant fint 1. ID at table and ends code.

Comment: **Why** do you want to renumber your records? What’s the issue with having the IDs starting at 2?

Answer (score 0):

You can’t easily do that. But *you don’t need to*. IDs are for *internal* identification of records in the database, not for external use (as in your example).

To iterate over all records in a database, don’t iterate over IDs. In general you *cannot* assume that IDs are sequential. Instead, iterate over the records directly:

```
for usercode in objects.all():
    print(usercode.id)
```